# Predicate to filter non constants from a list

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a predicate only_atoms/2(List+, Result-) that I'd like to filter non atoms.

For example :

```
only_atoms([1, 2, X, h(Y), 'aba'], Result).
```

should return

```
Result = [1, 2, 'aba'].
```

I do not care about the order.

Here is the piece of code I came up with :

```
only_atoms([], []) :- !.
only_atoms([Head | Tail], [Head | Result]) :-
    atom(Head),
    !,
    only_atoms(Tail, Result).
only_atoms([_ | Tail], Result) :-
    only_atoms(Tail, Result).
```

I thought this was the right kind of reasoning to handle such a problem but seem to be wrong since it yields me [](edit : it actually yields [aba], see precisions below, my bad !) no matter what. I'd appreciate some help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first hint: for `1` and `2`, `atom` returns `false`.

By the way, I was looking for the *filter* predicate, in the standard library it happens to be called `include`, it's usually better if you use what the language already provides ;-)

```
?- include(atom, [1, 2, X, h(Y), 'aba'], Result).
Result = [aba].
```

or if you wanted just to filter out variables:

```
?- exclude(var, [1, 2, X, h(Y), 'aba'], Result).
Result = [1, 2, h(Y), aba].
```

Another by the way, one curious difference between your `only_atoms` and using `include(atom, ...)` is that yours will unify variables in the first list with atoms in the second list, whereas the `include` won't.

```
?- only_atoms([1, x, 2, Y], [x, y]).
Y = y.

?- include(atom, [1, x, 2, Y], [x, y]).
false.
```

Those subtleties of Prolog always astonish me (I guess that's because I didn't pay enough attention at the university xD).

Comment: Hum I'm embarassed, I was certain to have tested atom for constants and variables. Then I checked again data types in prolog and discovered numbers and strings weren't the same kind of constants ~~
Thank you, I just added ;number(Head) after atom(Head) and it works fine.
Sorry again for the failed assumptions ;(

Comment: I thought that was known and the target was `['aba']` only.

Comment: @Orbling - OP was reporting that the result was the empty list. I don't see how this solves that particular issue, but OP says it does, so all's well that ends well.

Comment: yup I actually thought numbers, atoms and so on were all constants and treated the same so my code example was a number only thing and this one happened to have atoms in it, it's my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to force the `Head` not to be an atom on the alternate clause, otherwise it is an option for atoms as well.

This returns `Result = ['aba']` for me.

```
only_atoms([], []).
only_atoms([Head | Tail], [Head | Result]) :- atom(Head), !, only_atoms(Tail, Result).
only_atoms([Head | Tail], Result) :- \+atom(Head), !, only_atoms(Tail, Result).
```

Alternatively, you could try using [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall%2F3).

```
atoms_list(List, Result) :- findall(Item, (member(Item, List), atom(Item)), Result).
```

Comment: The second clause has a cut after `atom(Head)`. Wouldn't that prevent it from backing up to the third clause when `Head` is an atom?

Comment: yeah normally backtracking is cut during the second clause

Comment: @Ted Hopp: I wouldn't want it to backup if `Head` is an atom.  If I remove the cut, then the execution will wait to check for alternatives.  With the cut it returns instantly with a definite answer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the cut be removed. I was questioning the need to force `Head` not to be an atom on the alternate clause; it can't get there unless `Head` is not an atom.